# How to create KeyPair from string for BouncyCastle Decription?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm working on a decription method for a service I'm creating using BouncyCastle. The method should look something like this:

```
    public string RSADecryptString(string inputString, string privateKey)
    {
        //decription process here
    }
```

The method receives 2 parametes:

1. inputString = String of encrypted data that I want to decrypt.
2. privateKey = String of the private key to decrypt my inputString (the key is generated with BouncyCastle)

The generated private key looks like this:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEA1d22OTGqObdaC1UZUu93fMI+MnpSTho8GNgP1ANjDT4KtcmRpe7pBCVCtBNmUJU3kLimXRLtbZDnrrpdaHVadNPdhJrd3G6Ofx3KHkC+dSgtQhEXkgs2lmrG8pnM/1Mn69pAQIxfitSw19gxIfdgtkQTl2Lh4FJMDFyC1FwneSzmaOnAjGDc3kFyUg5EMRgbD7/HgU4ULUDLvlOBi6tjpRrbDBnf+G5fcFmo8Aw5f1Hw/KR6KVcirR0RKrJyOhMgFfRZsaS9Ngj4GlCt0Kzl8VCQAdGEQrXeFShxX7ffrQa6TUJ26pZVFw5WtskprQefU5LWfOkb9JErsi6kcVyu7QIDAQABAoIBAQCf0PSxPMnmI3voaAlqjoSN+GGeOwZyUuyB7EO3vWgxpyE9w4lRpH0Amg+EndKheUByp2m6t8AxVk2rppzSyI92KjSpOUl9xig6GbrGbL9msUVQz5D7k+GQ+e39sK0eR7fXadsF4WAsUNBuG6JrrX7Z9XlmcYA1r4og2qjxpIPi6iqqS2DCaN4+Y/PgsouBsnWtpmSnPUihwM9Zn76CQ7a2FJgVF2eif1eZ8I/fzf5bUYAgpSvCbR//0Z3T78XDmbBuKFahpqKyreB2fmh9tlMZRQjuy6jlfU9SOHBRnyAoqpJU72fmFcLZEBaYT+jTCTWkQVuxMn3voV/jTDh1s6ABAoGBAPPdqA43ZIUwWGIORjUuHrMKZvSRi7v9IZdWFygpNiUvKrWcsNdigfmjKgisZfuGR+lh58w6I8P1k/mwk11VNC38KU2N3Z5yvkzlIYxHhnBjixmhjfx772VB7mmmVknDGWi9QeKkGlZ4dMnFCebHZcPF+nuQ4YWCXbhoXSJhbyQBAoGBAOCB66Z89I+YEeMWXWPZTXwig8UDVz+9aEQAyFBMsMRXqlcrRTZoiQQzqRPGP36AcmvKFtj8/E3D5Q/hAaoFSxD2nBI0FIto7iE6GofKdJTmCcgcQ7MCqGEt7nDtf/piA6z1ZEI9xwrzmcWbE5I15uVSB8z6XKEb7GILmlnq0FrtAoGAMZn6Hrohlf2ZXIhuu05gLCaHfmNEOr5n4LJAD4kiXDnVxA7U4VpF+ZK4b/8w1xIe+ldRoHaK48bFjFnf/3HfJSNO+1lJpHrOPjG0uyWpMJ7uog38JUjIDp50ccTFdEdcmbM0/XZHbSMfDhMnymrwRfu00QFM/azghyujFeUfiAECgYBVlHDVuBAppJg87kuPQkhtJ2L/eLSLkZHrSjkRkwpW7ev66n2prdN9DIxJA2s0t5XmTNTExjsPEbuBgA34V6gzwS3hKoUiV09ezx1J4fzqvX3BEDUmSb8RvEaGOaJtOWuZRLmBHrd/DzjwwJqHQ5DOnaRnmJAywcgr36xo1j+ySQKBgQDEwVzruJYXu6MSoiVd0NKeZ2+A1zIdSBPHTiL2c2ofEYFc+OFHxu4bMWbINzN4nn7MM3zSB6WollBrgj2HoSHHoMQGb4QZEKj6Orv3Tg9AbzgbWDiPZ12mboEpaJLaqQFbJbv1aIJoCFL890NMBLpad9xvyrwBTSK4dHOJyTrqGg==-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

I saw a working example from this site: https://www.programmersought.com/article/19041424475/

Their c# example has the Encrypt and Decrypt logic I need to implement but the problem is that they generate their keys in the same method. I've also seen many StackOverflow questions where there are examples on how to read private keys from PEM files, but in my case I don't have any PEM file I just have my private key on a string.

I thought about generating a PEM file containing the private key of my string but that doesn't seem efficient at all.

I've tried using TextReaders to turn my string into something my PemReader object can read but it always returns null and from what I've read is because of a parsing error. I've also tried removing the "----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----" parts to try and solve the parsing error but it didn't. Here's an example of what I've tried.

```
    public string RSADecryptString(string inputString, string pK)
    {
        TextReader textReader = new StringReader(pK);
        PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(textReader);
        object privateKeyObject = pemReader.ReadObject();
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)privateKeyObject;

        //AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)pemReader.ReadObject();
        Console.WriteLine(keyPair.ToString());
        RsaKeyParameters privateKey = (RsaKeyParameters)keyPair.Private;

        IAsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new RsaEngine();
        Console.WriteLine("privateKey: " + privateKey.ToString());

        cipher.Init(false, keyPair.Private);
        byte[] bytesl = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);
        byte[] deciphered = cipher.ProcessBlock(bytesl, 0, bytesl.Length);
        string decipheredText = _encoding.GetString(deciphered);

        return decipheredText;
    }
```

I've been thinking if there is a way to create the KeyPair object my decrypt method needs with only my private key string, something like a SetPrivateKey method. I'm very new to BouncyCastle and don't know if I'm going the right way.

Any sugestions on how to proceed?

Comment: With a line break immediately after the header and immediately before the footer, the key can be loaded successfully, as demonstrated online here https://dotnetfiddle.net/e3ocxh.

Comment: @Topaco it worked. Thanks a lot. If its not too much to ask, can I ask you another question? My decrypted text is returning with a lot of wierd characteres, do you know what may be causing it? Here's an example of an input string and private key that I'm using https://dotnetfiddle.net/lhgEX1

Comment: @Topaco If it helps I'm being told that the way the inputString is being cyphered is this one:

`RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = DecodeX509PublicKey(DecodeOpenSSLPublicKey(xmlString));

return Convert.ToBase64String(rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString), false));`

Comment: During encryption PKCS#1 v1.5 padding was used. This must also be applied for decryption see here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C92KwB.

Comment: @Topaco worked perfectly. Thank your very much. Do you mind if I ask how did you noticed PKCS encryption was used? I'd like to learn how did you recognize it so I can do it in the future. And again thanks for your help.

Comment: This can be derived from your 2nd comment. The `false` in [`RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(..., false)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.encrypt?view=net-5.0) specifies PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: @Topaco thanks a lot for your help. :)